# Hadoop confs for client application

Tags: hadoop

I have a client application that uses the hadoop conf files (hadoop-site.xml and hadoop-core.xml)

I don't want to check it in on the resources folders, so I try to add it via idea. 
The problem is that the hadoop Confs ignores my HADOOP_CONF_DIR and loads the default confs from the hadoop package. Any ideia ?

I'm using gradle

Comment: You need them in `src/main/resources`, but it will load `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` first.

Answer (score 0):

I end up solving it by putting the configuration  files on test resources folder. So when the jar gets build it does not take it.